# Unable to install ubuntu 16.10 on a PC with Nvidia GTX1080

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, 16.10

I'm trying to install the new Ubuntu 16.10 from scratch.

When I select "tTry Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" from the installation menu the monitor just turns off. I can hear system sounds but can't see anything on the screen.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076

Comment: You need a Grub parameter - *nomodeset* - during installation and until you install the recommended Nvidia proprietary drivers for GTX1080.

Comment: @Vovan The link above in Becerra's comment shows you how to add *nomodeset* in a BIOS/MBR installation. If you see the installation menu in a black background that means UEFI/GPT installation (Which is correct and recommended wherever supported). Instead of using F6 select "Try Ubuntu", press 'e' (edit) and write *nomodeset* after or instead of *quiet splash* .

Comment: Would you mind testing the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics?